# Web3 trace filter method not exist in nodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, web3js

I'm trying to get internal transactions. Everything running fine except below code.

Below is code snippet im using.

```
const Web3 = require('web3');
const web3explorer = require('web3-explorer');

web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider(`ws://RPC ADDRESS`));

web3explorer(web3);

const filter = { 'fromBlock': '0x...', 'toAddress': [addr] };

web3.trace.filter(filter, (err, tx) => {
    console.log(err)
    if (err || !tx) {
        console.error(`TraceWeb3 error :${err}`);
    }
});
```

**Output:**

> Error: Returned error: the method trace_filter does not exist/is not available

This is how my package.json looks like

- "web3": "^1.0.0-beta.37"
- "web3-explorer": "1.0.2"

Answer (score 0):

The `trace_filter` RPC method is implemented in the OpenEthereum node software (see their [docs](https://openethereum.github.io/JSONRPC-trace-module#trace_filter)).

It's their custom method built on top of the official Ethereum JSON-RPC API ([docs](https://eth.wiki/json-rpc/API)).

So when you're connected to a different node software than OpenEthereum, this method is not guaranteed to be available.

**Solution:** Connect to a node provider running OpenEthereum that has this method available.